# How to execute next stage in Azure Devops Release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure devops, Release pipeline, I am trying to run a stage after two different stage as below. I am facing issue in running the API-test stage.

1. Dev stage is auto triggered.
2. QA stage is manual triggered.
3. API-test is needs to run either Dev/QA is successful.

[image]

**Expected:**

API-test needs to run if either Dev or QA stage is successful.

**Actual:**

API-test stage is not triggered when Dev stage is successful.

Kindly let me know the required configuration.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workaround of using rest api. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Besides of duplicating the API-Test stage, another workaround is to use [Update Release Environment rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-6.1). See below steps:

1, Set **API-Test** stage only be auto triggered after **Dev** stage.

[image]

2, Go the **security** page of your release edit page.
[image]

Set the **Manage deployments** to **allow** for account **yourProjectname Build Service(Your Organization)**. This persmission will allow you to update the release environment in the release pipeline.

[image]

3, Go to **QA** stage-->In the Agent job section-->Check `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`. This setting will allow you to use the accesstoken in the release pipeline.

[image]

4, After above preparation, you can now add a script task at the **end of QA stage** to call the release rest api. See below example in powershell task:

```
#Get releaseresponse
$Releaseurl= "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{yourOrg}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=6.0-preview.8" 

$releaseresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $Releaseurl

#Get the environment ID of API-Test stage from the release response:
$id = $releaseresponse.environments |  Where-Object{$_.name -match "API-Test"} | select id

#Create the JSON body for the deployment:
$deploymentbody = @" 
{"status": "inprogress"} 
"@
#Invoke the REST method to trigger the deployment to API-Test stage:
$DeployUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{yourOrg}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)/environments/$($id.id)?api-version=6.0-preview.7" 

$DeployRelease = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Uri $DeployUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -Body $deploymentbody
```

Above scripts first call [get Release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the environment id of API-Test stage.
Then call the update release environment rest api to trigger the deployment to API-Test.

So that above script can achieve the API-Test stage be triggered after manually Deployment to QA stage is successfully.